# create tables on docker start

Tags: mysql, sql, docker

I am new to docker, i have created my application and i want to send to another developer but i cant seem to run it running docker.

It says tables dont exist. I have read the docker doc but i dont get it.

The table are not created.

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

my dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

COPY ./dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

my docker-composer

```
version: '2'

volumes:
    logs:
        driver: local

services:
    slim:
        build: .
        working_dir: /var/www
        command: php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public
        environment:
            docker: "true"
        depends_on:
          - db-mysql
        ports:
            - 80:8080
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
            - logs:/var/www/logs
        links:
          - db-mysql

    db-mysql:
      image: mysql
      restart: always
      container_name: db-mysql
      ports:
        - "3307:3306"
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: path
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      volumes:
        - ./mysql_init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        - ./dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

and my dump.sql has

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST `paths` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lat` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `long` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `token` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I think the `dump.sql` file is supposed to be copied in the `mysql` image, not the `php:7.1-apache`.

Comment: I dont understand, please can you show me in codes

Comment: I've written an answer here: [Dockerize MySQL with database and tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239766/dockerize-mysql-with-database-and-tables/44240369#44240369).

Comment: ok but can i have 2 froms in my Dockerfile like FROM php and FROM mysql

Comment: You can define different `Dockerfiles` for each service. But this means that you will have to change `build: .` and use actual paths to Dockerfiles.

Comment: let me give it a try

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add your entrypoint script to your database. Not to your application (the dockerfile is not clear for me). For more detail you can look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713597/create-table-in-postgresql-docker-image/38714511#38714511).

docker-compose.yml (basic without persistency)

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  mysql:
   image: mysql
   restart: always
   container_name: db-mysql
   ports:
    - 3307:3306
   environment:
     MYSQL_DATABASE: path
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
     MYSQL_USER: testuser
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: testpassword
   volumes:
    - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

first check the users. A root user does already exist by default so give the mysql_user a different name. secondly I mount a directory, not a file. I have a dir `dump` which contains my `dump.sql` (very basic too):

```
CREATE TABLE paths (
  id int(11)
)
```

Tree looks like this:

```
docker-compose.yml
dump/
```

`dump/` contains `dump.sql`

During container startup this is `dump/` directory mounted inside the mysql container.

```
$ docker-compose up -d

docker exec -it db-mysql bash
```

Authenticate (you can choose, root_user of normal user) I use the normal one:

```
root@a110fe08e4b6:/# mysql -u testuser -p
Enter password:
```

Check db's:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| path               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

use path and check tables:

```
mysql> use path;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_path |
+----------------+
| paths          |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

show columns from paths table:

```
mysql> show columns from paths;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: lemme give your solution a try

Comment: what's the error? I've tested it (printed the outputs) so it should work.

Comment: no errors just this mysql> use path;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Did you copy past my docker-compose.yml file? and the same dump dir and dump.sql. Start from there. When it works you can update the dump.sql etc.

Comment: when i run your code i get this:yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 8, column 5
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 24, column 6

Comment: It's a valid yaml (check here: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) I'm sorry. I can't help you copy pasting.

Comment: in my case, error is due to sql syntax. please check the docker log may helpful.